# C: Removing white space from sentence; Exception thrown: write access violation

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am writing a palindrome function in c, and it has to be able to handle sentences, so I need to delete the spaces in the word in order for it to work. My actual function for seeing if it is a palindrome works fine, but I am getting an "Exception thrown: write access violation.

temp was 0x1346E3C.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."
error when I try and remove the white space.

Here is main

```
    char * palindrome = "sex at noon taxes";
int pal = 0;

pal = is_palindrome(palindrome, 5);

if (pal == 1)
{
    printf("This word is palindrome\n");
}
if (pal == 0)
{
    printf("This word is not a palindrome\n");
}
```

and here is the function

```
    int is_palindrome(char *word, int length)
/*
This function will determine if a word is a palindrome
*/
{
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    char *cpy = word, *temp = word;

    while (*cpy)
    {
        if (*cpy != ' ')
        {
            *temp++ = *cpy;
        }
        cpy++;
    }
    *temp = 0;

    if (length <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (word[0] != word[--length])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return is_palindrome(++word, --length);
    }
}
```

the error comes up on the

```
        *temp++ = *cpy;
```

And help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: String literals are put into a read-only memory when compiling. You can't change their contents.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Is there anyway for the function to ignore white space them? I thought char * palindrome made it mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char * palindrome = "sex at noon taxes";
```

The string `palindrome` points to constant string, you cannot change any elements of it.

Either change it to

```
 char * palindrome = strdup("sex at noon taxes");
```

or

```
 char palindrome[] = "sex at noon taxes";
```

Comment: Also remember to free memory allocated by `strdup` after done using it.

Comment: Or `char *palindrome = (char[]){ "sex at noon taxes" };` using a *compound literal*.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
  char * palindrome = "sex at noon taxes";
```

is equivalent to

```
  const char * palindrome = "sex at noon taxes";
```

This means that palindrome points at a string which is located
in read only memory.  So you cannot modify the contents.

Try

```
 char palindrome[] = "sex at noon taxes";
```

BTW, is this a new tax?

Comment: It says "sex at noon taxes".